# Twitter Bootstrap CMS

Tags: php

Ok, so I started to build my own CMS. You can see [Aleksandar Golubovic's Blog](http://cms.golubovic.info),and I need your help. Please, look at my code, and tell me is that safe? You can download current version from [Twitter Bootstrap CMS](http://cms.golubovic.info/tb-cms.rar). If you want to install it, just read instructions.

So, please, tell me if I get some errors, or some of your opinions, instructions... I really need help.

EDIT:

I have many functions like:

```
function DeletePost()
{
if (isset($_GET['action']))
{
    if ($_GET['action']==='delete-post' && !isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC");
        while ($arr=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {
        echo '<div class="span8 offset1"><p><h3>'.$arr['post_title'].'</h3> <a href="javascript:;" title="Delete This Post" class="delete" id="'.$arr['id'].'">Delete this post</a></p><p>'.$arr['post_content'].'</p></div>';
        }
    }
    if ($_GET['action']==='delete-post' && isset($_GET['id']))
    {

            $del=$_GET['id'];
            $qry=mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id='$del'") or die ("ERROR!!!");
            echo "This post has been successfull deleted.";


    }
}
}
```

And this function is included in some page. So my question is: Is this method safe?
Note: All functions is separeted pages using .htaccess

Comment: This site is for code review only. IE: You post a piece of code and a question concerning the posted code and we review it and offer help on what you should do. This is not a website review board, etc. Perhaps try http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or stack overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well looking at this as a code review of the code you posted i can recommend a couple of things;

### Security

The major flaw at the moment is the possibility for SQL injection. You put the $_GET values directly into the query without validation or escaping.

PHP.net has a page on SQL injection:  http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

### Deprecated code

*It is strongly recommend **not** to use the `mysq_*` functions*. !!!

These functions are deprecated and will recieve no more support and will be removed in an upcoming version of PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php and look at the big red box. This is potentially a huge security hazzard in the future as well.

### User Content / Access levels

Currently you are not demonstrating any check on access level. If i am to guess your actions i could delete the entire content of your website without logging in!

### Database connection

You seem to open the sql connection somewhere else. Please verify for yourself that you also close the connection when request ends, avoiding lingering MySQL connections.

### Misc

Also, look into the SOLID principles and PSR-2 codestyle, your current code does not match it. These are best practices and provide a good base strategy for your coding. Also, making it more likely the open source community would accept/adopt your code.

Good luck in further development of your CMS!

Comment: Where can one find information regarding psr-2 codestyle that you speak of?

Comment: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md . Please note, PSR-2 extends PSR-1 (link in above page) which in turn extends PSR-0

Comment: Thanks!!! This is the best answer I can get! I dont have enough points to vote for your answer, but as soon as I get some, I will vote!